# Threads Having Same Priority

Tags: java, multithreading

### Interview Question:

10 threads having same priority in waiting state,ready  to access a resource then which thread will access the resource for java

Comment: The answer is **we cannot know**

Comment: The one which is woken up?

Comment: The thread that executes first, of course... which one that is, nobody knows.

Comment: With 10% probability, the thread 7

Answer (score 1):

One of them, but no guarantees which one.

Answer (score 0):

If two or more threads have same priority, any thread can execute. It totally depends CPU of the system on which threads are running. In such a cases the scheduler chooses one of them to run in a round-robin fashion. 
http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/threads/priority.html

Answer (score 0):

Threads have some priority. Because of that thread scheduler assign processor to thread. It is possible to have same priority to threads. So CPU can decide which thread to run by using some algorithms.